# where can I get the source code for traceroute in IPv6

Tags: c

I am looking for the source code for traceroute in linux. specially I am looking for the code of traceroute6 which is the traceroute for IPv6. I have found similar questions in stackoverflow, but those were not much of a help. can anyone pls suggest me any link or place where I can get the sourcecode of traceroute for IPv6 in C ?

Comment: Search sourceforge for "iputils"

Answer (score 0):

The source is maintained by sourceforge.net [here](http://traceroute.sourceforge.net/)